# cuda, addAtomic producing odd results

Tags: cuda

I have a situation where addAtomic is not performing as I would  expect. I am very new to cuda so I am likely missing something, however ive been stuck on this for nearly a good day and rewritten most other areas of my program thinking it was a memory allocation issue. This doesnt seem to be the case though.

Essentially what is happening is that it calls the 'analyze' kernel which should be producing min/max and sum values of the data. The same data is used for min/max as the sum. The result from the atomicadd operation however, read like a memory address. very very large numbers. Is there something I am missing - I have gone over this a hundred times and stripped out almost everything out of the kernel except for the min/max and sum.

```
__global__ void analyze(int *data, int *min, int *max, int *mean)
{
    int t_id = (threadIdx.x * AXIS_COUNT) + blockIdx.x;
    int b_id = blockIdx.x;

    int localVal = data[t_id];
    atomicMin(&min[b_id], localVal);
    atomicMax(&max[b_id], localVal);
    atomicAdd(&mean[b_id], localVal);
}
    ...........
    int r;
    int step = WINDOW_LENGTH * AXIS_COUNT;
    for (r = 0; r < out_rows; r++){
        analyze<<<AXIS_COUNT, WINDOW_LENGTH>>>(
                                                &d_data[r * step], 
                                                &d_min[r * AXIS_COUNT], 
                                                &d_max[r * AXIS_COUNT],
                                                &d_mean[r * AXIS_COUNT]);
    }

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(h_min, d_min, int_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(h_max, d_max, int_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(h_mean, d_mean, int_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(r=0; r < out_rows; r++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mean %d, x: %d, y: %d z: %d\n", r, h_mean[r*AXIS_COUNT], h_mean[r*AXIS_COUNT + 1], h_mean[r*AXIS_COUNT+2]);
    }
```

The result are in the form:

```
mean 5025, x: 2078310793, y: 1999653847 z: -1453684997
mean 5026, x: 2078308025, y: 1999646363 z: -1453660854
mean 5027, x: 2078305391, y: 1999639383 z: -1453636904
mean 5028, x: 2078304342, y: 1999630356 z: -1453613212
```

I have validated and checked the min/max values with the relevant documents to confirm.

Comment: CUDA is **not** C!

Comment: You haven't shown the part where you initialize `d_mean` to zero. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @tera: and I am pretty sure that is the root cause here, but who knows....

Comment: You need to post the complete code. I don't know what `int_size` is set to, but if it is what I think it is, you're not copying the whole array between device and host.

Answer (score -3):

The answer was to initialize the shared memory in the kernel.

```
__shared__ double sum[AXIS_COUNT];
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < AXIS_COUNT; i++) 
            sum[i] = 0;
    }


    syncthreads();
    int t_id = (threadIdx.x * AXIS_COUNT) + blockIdx.x;
    int b_id = blockIdx.x;
```

Comment: The kernel in your question didn't have any shared memory usage in it. So how would initialising shared memory change anything?